# How to omit stage name from url in AWS Api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

How can i omit stage name in API endpoint url for Amazon API Gateway.

For example instead of api.domain.com/stagename/resource/ I would like to have api.domain.com/resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change stage from API URL, which is the implementation of API gateway but you can give the custom domain to your API URL if you want.

If you are using custom domain name then stage is optional - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html#how-to-custom-domains-console

or with CloudFormation template - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-basepathmapping.html

Comment: Then stage is optional - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html#how-to-custom-domains-console

Comment: Although it appears that stage is optional, API can be only accessed with url containing a stage name.